# Custom generated column value with persistent sequence for mySQL in Java Springboot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, sequence

Given a table in a **mySQL** database looks like this with the following columns:

```
| id  | name | reference|
```

- **id** is a big-int auto-generated when persisting
- **name** is a varchar
- **reference** is a varchar

I am currently using **spring-boot** with **spring-jpa**.

Is there a way when I am persisting this entity to have the reference column be auto-generated in a custom way only when it is null. For example:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(name,reference) VALUES('John', 'MREF-System-0940');
```

Will produce a result as follows

```
| id  | name | reference        |
| 1   | John | MREF-System-0940 |
```

But when I execute the following

```
INSERT INTO my_table(name) VALUES('John');
```

Will produce a result as follows (Where reference is based as 'REF-{name}-{sequence}' where sequence could be the id or a predefined persistent sequence)

```
| id  | name | reference  |
| 2   | John | REF-John-2 |
```

It should auto-generate the reference column **reference** when it detects that column is null when persisting the entity.

If possible could we append the generated **id** column at the end? If not, is there a feasible way of auto-generating a reference as such.

Meaning if we do

```
INSERT INTO my_table(name) VALUES('Bob');
```

It might produce a result as follows

```
| id  | name | reference   |
| 3   | Bob  | REF-Bob-001 |
```

Comment: Are you using SQL for generate column?

Comment: @RafaelPizao for the id yes I am using database to auto increment. For the reference I am open to using java or database. I prefer java based as I can configure in future without redeployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make JPA generate field value you should use `myEntityRepository#save` instead of the native modifying query.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    String name;
    String reference;

    public MyEntity(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    //getters, setters, toString, hashcode, equals

    @PostPersist
    public void setReferencePostPersist(){
        if(id != null) {
            reference = "REF-" + name + "-" + id;
        }
    }
}
```

then

```
@Autowired
MyEntityRepository repository;

public MyEntity saveNewMyEntity(String name) {
    MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity(name);   
    return repository.save(myEntity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. Just add a null check in the postPersist method and all good to go.